# JQuery DatePicker not loading - Issue with DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom, datepicker

I think I have an issue with my datepicker because of the DOM.  Basically, I load my forms html from a database.  In my template, I have something like the following

```
{!! $documentData->form_data !!} //this will load my forms html

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p> //this is a test
```

I then have the following

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    });
});
```

Now the form loaded from the database has an text input with a class datepicker.  I then also have the test line underneath.  When the form loads, when I click in one of these inputs nothing loads.  If I do this however

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>  

{!! $documentData->form_data !!}
```

The test line will work, but the form from the database with the correct input will not.  This is why I think it has something to do with the DOM - because it works if loaded before the form is injected into the template.

So really, I am just keen to understand why this happens, and what solution I could apply to this?

Thanks

Comment: Did your form html loaded through AJAX?

Comment: No. I am using Laravel, so it is loaded through routes

Comment: Sorry , I am not familiar with laravel. Is there any option, when form html loaded after that you have to reload datepicker again

Comment: Like this: $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that jquery ui is included in the webpage? Jquery and jquery ui is two different script. jquery ui is needed to attach a datepicker to an input. Check your webpage DOM in order to confirm that jquery-ui is loading.

Comment: They are both included.  If one was missing, the datepicker would not load when I put the test input before the injection of my html form from the database